# Why my Common Table Expression query doesn't work with Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Server version : 8.0.19 MySQL Community Server

I have 2 tables: Channel and User_message.

```
mysql> describe Channel;
+--------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| channel_id   | int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| channel_name | text | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe User_message;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| message_id | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| channel_id | int          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| user_id    | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| timestamp  | float        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I'm trying to use CTE expression like:

```
 WITH `vals` (`uid`, `cid`) AS (VALUES (816, 97), (1, 97), (754, 10)) SELECT `t1`.`message_id`, `t1`.`channel_id`, `t1`.`user_id`, `t1`.`timestamp` FROM `User_message` AS `t1` INNER JOIN `vals` ON ((`t1`.`user_id` = `vals`.`uid`) AND (`t1`.`channel_id` = `vals`.`cid`));
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(816, 97), (1, 97), (754, 10)) SELECT `t1`.`message_id`, `t1`.`channel_id`, `t1`' at line 1
```

While this query works fine with SQLite, why?

Comment: The issue is not `WITH`.  It is `VALUES`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing this as:

```
WITH `vals` (`uid`, `cid`) AS (
       VALUES ROW(816, 97), ROW(1, 97), ROW(754, 10)
      )
SELECT *
FROM vals;
```

In MySQL, `VALUES` requires the explicit `ROW()` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `union all` :

```
WITH `vals` (`uid`, `cid`) AS (
      SELECT 816 AS `uid`, 97 AS `cid` UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 AS `uid`, 97 AS `cid` UNION ALL
      SELECT 757 AS `uid`, 10 AS `cid`
      )
SELECT *
FROM vals;
```